# Php MySQL Query is out of memory in hosting with limited resources

Tags: php, mysql, bigdata

Hello everyone before anything I want to set important facts that cannot be changed:

- The hosting can't be changed
- The php_ini max memory setted in php won't work
- The php.ini cannot be edited
- The php can't be updated

We have a webapi (similar to a restful service) where with an url, the users can be shown in a json way. But we have 85k+ records, when we try to brig them all, the php crashes (that doesn't happen when we look just for 1 record), we have 2 codes to work with, but none of them bring all the users

Version 1

```
<?php
//security variables
$variableName = 'name';
$variableValue = 'value';

//system variables

ob_end_flush();
ob_start();
if(isset($_GET[$variableName]) && $_GET[$variableName]== $variableValue){
    $dbVars = array();
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM users_data ';
    foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {

        if( $key != $variableName && $key != 'sized' && $key != 'devmode'){
            array_push($dbVars, $key."='".$value."'");
        }
    }
    if( count($dbVars) > 0 ){

        $query .= 'WHERE '.implode(' AND ', $dbVars);
    }
    $result = mysql($w['database'], $query);
    $results = array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        array_push($results, $row);
    }
    echo json_encode($results);
}
?>
```

Version 2 (using flush)

```
<?php
//security variables
$variableName = 'name';
$variableValue = 'value';

//system variables

ob_end_flush();
ob_start();
if(isset($_GET[$variableName]) && $_GET[$variableName]== $variableValue){
    $dbVars = array();
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM users_data ';
    foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {

        if( $key != $variableName && $key != 'sized' && $key != 'devmode'){
            array_push($dbVars, $key."='".$value."'");
        }
    }
    if( count($dbVars) > 0 ){

        $query .= 'WHERE '.implode(' AND ', $dbVars);
    }
    $result = mysql($w['database'], $query);
    echo "[";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $results = array(); 
        foreach($row as $key => $value){
            array_push($results, '"'.$key.'":"'.$value.'"');
        }
        echo '{'.implode(',',$results).'}';
        ob_flush();
    }
    echo "]";
}
?>
```

**When we want to get all the users in database are 85k, the result is none because memory limit 
How can we made this work for all the users?**

Comment: littlebobbytables... Anyway, what's the error exactly?

Comment: This code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks, and uses an obsolete DB library (mysql_*) which is likely to be vulnerable, since it hasn't been updated for many years, and is removed in PHP7. First change your DB library to something modern (mysqli, or better still, PDO) and learn to use parameterised/prepared queries.

Comment: Maybe don't call all record in one query ! and use jQuery/Ajax to call all records with limits in more querys.

Comment: @Sebas when we want to get all  the users in database are 85k, the result is none because memory limit

Comment: @Soheyl ajax/jquery does not have anything to do with how the backend api is implemented.

Comment: @ricardorios We need the **exact** error message :-)

Comment: @Soheyl is a web api we cannot use jquery there, maybe using limits could be a good option but the end user wants all of them

Comment: @ADyson we cannot update php as we described in the facts that we cannot change

Comment: @ricardorios if you can't change the code, you can't change the environment, and you can't change the settings, then how do you propose to solve the problem? What _can_ you change?

Comment: @ADyson he meant the version of the php libraries I suppose, not the php code. Or...?

Comment: @Sebas and ADyson maybe a hot fix, or a way to use unbuffered queries in this old php version

Comment: @Sebas Perhaps. Worrying though - if someone is resisting the removal of an obsolete and vulnerable library, especially at a point where the solution clearly needs modifying anyway, they want their head examining. Glad I'm not the client commissioning this software :-)

Comment: @ADyson yeah, we made this clear to the client, but he wants his old and obsolete server as it is

Comment: @ADyson I agree, but sometimes legacy code is truly immutable for reasons that go beyond developers decisions - edit: here you go

Comment: @ricardorios so what makes you think it´s a memory limit issue? And also, I think what´s asking ADyson is right: what can you change? Do you even have sudo/root access to the server?

Comment: @ricardorios I've been in organisations where we had that problem - client unwilling to upgrade, probably out of fear of change. Be clear though, if it gets hacked, they _will_ still blame _you_, even if you make them sign in blood that they understand the consequences.

Comment: If you can't change anything, warm up your resume.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, your code is filled to the brim with SQL injection vulnerabilities. Anyone can own your database. This is your problem.

Now, the reason PHP runs out of memory is that you are using **buffered queries**.

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.concepts.buffering.php

> Queries are using the buffered mode by default. This means that query results are immediately transferred from the MySQL Server to PHP and then **are kept in the memory of the PHP process**.

Read the link I provided (which uses mysqli, for chrissakes) and use unbuffered mode to stream your result set to the client.

Also, don't array_push() the entire result set into an array.

Also, obviously,

```
array_push($dbVars, $key."='".$value."'");
```

will generate invalid JSON if any value contains a " or other escape chars.